# I want make a query in django opposing of where?

Tags: python, django, models

E.g I have the models

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length="200")

class Answer(models.Model):
    question= models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

So, I want all Question's that I don't have in Answers

E.g In answer I have

```
Question 1
Question 2
```

and in Question I have

```
Question 1
Question 2
Question 3
Question 4
```

and I want like result of my Query Question 3 and Question 4

thanks

Comment: Isn't that what the `exclude` method is for?  Is this just a question about `exclude`?

Answer (score 6):

I *think* what you want is:

```
unanswered_questions = Question.objects.filter(answer__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to first get a distinct list of all question IDs in Answer, then get all Questions that do not have one of those IDs

```
ids = Answer.objects.all().distinct().values_list('question', Flat=True)
unanswered = Question.objects.all().exclude(pk__in=ids)
```